# Android - Changing item title in bottom navigation bar

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I have 2 fragments between which I can navigate with a bottom navigation bar. I also have an overflow menu with an item which shows an edittext dialog.

I want that when I write and validate text in the dialog, the currently displayed fragment's item on the nav bar changes of title. I don't know how to change text of a specific item.

I hope my question is understandable. I have been searching through SO but I didn't find any corresponding answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Kotlin

```
bottom_nav_view.menu.findItem(R.id.bottom_nav_item).title = "TITTLE"
```

in Java

```
bottom_nav_view.getMenu().findItem(R.id.bottom_nav_item).setTitle( "TITTLE")
```

Comment: That's it, thanks. And more precisely, `bottom_nav_view.getMenu().findItem(R.id.bottom_nav_item).setTitle("title")`

Answer (score 0):

If you define an id for the item you want to change in the layouts menu (add the line android:id="@+id/myid"), you can find that item in the code by using findViewById (R.id.myid). Then, just set the new the title depending on what the item is.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code I can only guess that you setup a [`ViewPager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) with the [`TabLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) method `yourTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(yourViewPagerAdapter);`.

If it is so, you can simply set a title using 
`yourTabLayout.getTabAt(position).setText(yourTitle);` where `position` is `0` for first tab and `1` for second tab.
If you post some code I can try to specify my answer on your code and the way you are adding the fragments to your activity.