# Set bottom navigation bar titles

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a bottom navigation bar and the app consists of Fragments.

MainActivity.kt

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)


        val bottomNavigationView = binding.bottomNavigation
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)

    val window = this.window

    window.statusBarColor = this.resources.getColor(R.color.primary_blue)
    }



}
```

Bottom_menu.xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
    android:title="Home"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_outlined" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/vacaturesFragment"
    android:title="Text1"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_text1_outlined" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/sollicitatiesFragment"
    android:title="Text2"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_text2_outlined" />
```

Now i want to programmatically change the titles(sow the text under the icons) of navigation bar items in the fragment. I have a MainFragment and a DetailFragment. Is this possible with binding.navigationbar.titel ?? Is this possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51326246/12187548

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the menu items in the bottom navigation view and change them in code

```
bottomNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id. mainFragment).setTitle("title")
```

If you want to change for vacaturesFragment or sollicitatiesFragment item just use their ids in the findItem call.

Comment: tx, thats working. The title text is changing depending on the chosen language by the User. Now the title is changing below the navigation icon. But only after restart of the app. Can i reload the fragment/activity to make the change directly after the user changes the language for the app (this is after a button click).

Comment: Yes for the language changes to reflect you need to reload the activity. Reloading fragment wont work

Comment: i understand, but how can i restart the MainActivity within in a Fragment, is that possible ?

Comment: You can use getActivity(). recreate();